# PowerBI - Service Principal access

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi

Trying to publish report in PowerBI using Service account. These are steps I did. I'm starting to learn this, so please correct me if I did anything wrong.

1. Created Microsoft 365 account, as Power BI wont take personal email to sign up.
2. Signed up for Power BI, activated pro account.
3. Need to invoke REST method, so I signed in using same Microsoft 365 account to Azure. With this account, when I try to add subscription, its taking me to page to select offers for subscription.

I have another Azure subscription, but I'm not able to change directory of Azure account I created with Microsoft 365, as I need subscription to do that.

So I thought fine, will do a subscription for Microsoft 365, but it has payment information with country defaulting to United States. It wont take my credit card info.

Is this wrong way of doing this automation? How to change directory without subscription, or should I dont even have to do this part?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the payment info defaulting to USA, you can change your geo location. [Use this list to find your](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/table-of-geographical-locations) `Geographical location identifier (Hex)`

then use this command to change it

```
  Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId $hex
```

Now try inputting your CC info, and it should show your country instead of USA.

Comment: Billing info is coming up in webpage. Is it depending on geo location? I ll try out your solution and update back